# How to execute some code on a specific datetime to the second?

Tags: php

I'm building a market place with auctions. I need to end auctions preferably at the exact second they are defined to end according to their record in the mysql database.

I know about CRON jobs and I'm currently running a CRON job every minute to execute some script which checks if there are sales that should end.

However this sometimes means that an auction ends almost a minute too late, which is not acceptable. Does anybody know how to make this more accurate without putting a lot of load on the server? For example I wouldn't want to run a script every second to check if sales have ended.

Comment: It's a bit broad (IMHO) as the idea of what it means by an auction ending and why you have to run a job to flag it as ended isn't necessary.  If a user tries to bid on something after the end date then their bid is easily rejected with an appropriate message.

Comment: "However this sometimes means that an auction ends almost a minute too late" Why does it even matter? Both new bids and Status requests should verify the date/time and should consider the auction closed if the auction end time is in not in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check timestamp everytime a user try to click auctions button. So even the page haven't refresh and times up, user is not able to bid your item.

Comment: Damn I feel stupid for not thinking about that, thanks.